# MATLAB is rounding my values to 1

Tags: matlab

```
n = 215;
N = 215.01:0.1:250;
p = 0.52;
q = 0.48;
Gamblers = (1 - (q/p)^n)./(1 - (q/p).^N);
plot(Gamblers)
```

Matlab takes the numerators and denominators as simply 1, filling the array with nothing but that value. How can I correct this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your denominator and numerator are **very** close to 1 but not exactly 1. The *plot(Gamblers)* confirms this.

By default MATLAB will display numbers with four digits after the decimal place. Your numerator is 0.999999966414861, which with four digits rounds to 1. MATLAB uses double precision numbers so your calculation here is still accurate.

Try double clicking on the *Gamblers* variable to open the variables window and then double clicking on one of the results. You'll see it change from the default display precision to a much more accurate depiction of your variable.

Comment: Ahhhhh you're right I didnt know about that function in matlab thank you.

Comment: No problem :) happy to help!